# Google search gem results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am using awesome [google-search](https://github.com/tj/google-search) gem for search some info in google.

This is my ruby (model Items belongs_to Product) :

```
require 'rubygems'
require "google-search"

  query = "Some query for google"
  Google::Search::Web.new do |search|
    search.query = query
    puts search.first.uri
  end
```

But often i got results not same like in my browser. I guess its all about my account, because google range searched data by my search history and google-search gem has no this history.

**Who know how i can solve this issue that got more relevant result from google ?**

Comment: _Sidenote_: What on the Earth you wanted to express by this construct: `result = "" = search.first.uri.to_s`? Should there be `==`?

Comment: Some not usual syntax) its just creating empty string object and put in it result of search, exactly  just 1st element of search results

Comment: Really? It looks like a syntax error to both me and ruby parser.

Comment: Ok, i change my code for single ruby program. But the main problem is not it my code, main problem is in the result of searching by google-search gem. I need configure it to search like from my google account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this gem is now deprecated, we built our own [gem](https://github.com/serpapi/google-search-results-ruby). It's quite simple to use:

```
query_params = {
  q: "query",
  google_domain: "Google Domain", 
  location: "Location Requested", 
  device: device,
  hl: "Google UI Language",
  gl: "Google Country",
  num: "Number of Results",
}
query = GoogleSearchResults.new query_params
hash_results = query.get_hash
html_results = query.get_html
json_results = query.get_json
```